# combining javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, function

Design and code a program which prompts a user for the year they were born, calculates the user's age and displays the user's age. If the user's age is over 40 then set the background color of the web page to red. The solution must use the JavaScript Date object and use programmer created functions for calculating the user's age.

pretty small problem i just need to make the screen turn red if age is more then 40 I just cant seem to make that happen...

```
    <html>
<head>
<title> Age of person </title>
<div id="age"></div>
<body>
<script>
function determine_age_of_person ( year )
{
var today = new Date();
var now_year = today.getFullYear();
var age = now_year - year_person_was_born;
return age;
}


var year_person_was_born;
//unsure about below statement the '==' part
var age_of_person==age;

do
{
year_person_was_born = prompt("Enter year you were born", "");
year_person_was_born = parseInt (year_person_was_born1 );
}

while (is(year_person_was_born));

age_of_person = determine_age_of_person ( year_person_was_born );

if (age_of_person>40)
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";

else
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";

document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = "You are " + age_of_person + " years old";


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code says to turn it red if they were born in a year greater than 40. You should use their age for that test.

Comment: So the person born on 2000-01-01 and the person born on 2000-12-31 have the same age?

Comment: Your HTML is incorrect; the div needs to be inside the `<body>` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok there are lot of code placement issues here (you have an html element outside of the `body` element, return statements outside of functions, function arguments that you don't use).  Here is a simplified version of what you are building ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79QMw/))

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title> Age of person </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="age"></div>
    <script>
      function determine_age_of_person (year) {
        return (new Date()).getFullYear() - year;
      }

      var age_of_person = determine_age_of_person(parseInt (prompt("Enter year you were born", ""), 10));

      if (age_of_person>40) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      } else {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }
    document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = "You are " + age_of_person + " years old";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is breakdown of the changes I made:

- Moved `<div id="age"></div>` inside the `body`
- Used argument `year` in `determine_age_of_person()` instead of global variable
- Combined `prompt`, `parseInt` and `determine_age_of_person` into one line (and added a radix to parseInt, because JavaScript has weird rules related to non base 10 numbers, it's a good habit to get into)
- Added curly braces to `if statement`
- Removed useless code like `do()` and `while()`

Comment: thanks Jason Sperske i dont have the rep allowed to +1 your post but thank you very much !!

Answer (score 2):

change

```
if (year_person_was_born > 40)
```

to

```
if (age_of_person > 40)
```

Comment: You'll also want to add `return age;` to `determine_age_of_person`

Comment: ^ Correct - or since you have `age_of_person` as a global variable - you could just set age_of_person to the result of `now_year - year`. I'm not sure why you have `parseInt` there around the result of that subtraction - I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: `return age;` would need to be the last statement inside the function. Nothing else in the function will run after that line executes.